# change specific node attribute name in igraph in python

Tags: python, igraph

I have an attribute called `name` in a graph `g`. I would like to change the name of one specific node associated with the attribute to a different name.

For example I have

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph(4)
g.vs['name'] = [(10,1), (269,1331), (3,1), (10,10)]
print g.vs['name']
[(10,1), (269,1331), (3,1), (10,10)]
```

I would like `(3,1)` to know be called `(4,10)`, so the output should be

```
print g.vs['name']
[(10,1), (269,1331), (4,10), (10,10)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the index of the node that is currently called `(3, 1)`:

```
index = g.vs["name"].index((3, 1))
```

Then, change the name of the node with that index:

```
g.vs[index]["name"] = (4, 10)
```